# SIGABRT when trying to add atributes in entity. Core Data on iOs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, sigabrt, nsentitydescription

My app receive SIGABRT when i'm trying to add atributes to my Entity.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[[HistoryDataManager sharedInstance] mainObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription * entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Request" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Request *request=[[[Request alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"request: %@", request);
    request.requestText=string;
    request.timeStamp=[NSDate date];
    [context insertObject:request];
    NSError * error;  
    if (![context save:&error]) {  
        NSLog(@"Saving error  : %@", [error userInfo]);  
    }
```

I've got entity with name Request and context!=nil, but I've got SIGABRT message everytime at this place:

```
NSEntityDescription * entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Request" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Can we have the full SIGABRT message ?

Comment: Somehow there is no SIGABRT message in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `context` is nil. Pass a nil managed object context value will usually cause a crash. Confirm that you have a value in `context` before passing it to the method.

Check the entity name as well.

Comment: I have value in context and i definitely have entity with name Request

Answer (score -3):

Problem was in my DataManager singleton, sorry for wasting your time.